# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars, attempting to plot a contrast versus exit angle

Tags: python, numpy, plot

I am attempting to create a plot using the following code:

```
from math import *
from numpy import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def contrast(R, a0):
    C = (((R*a0)**2)-((1-2*R*a0)**2))/(((R*a0)**2)+((1-2*R*a0)**2))
    return C

def theta_dependence(nin, nout, thetain, thetaout):
    R = ((nin*cos(thetain)-nout*cos(thetaout))/(nin*cos(thetain)+nout*cos(thetaout)))**2
    return R

def convert_degrees(degrees):
    rtheta = (2*pi*degrees)/360.0
    return rtheta

def find_thetaout(nout, thetain):
    thetaout = asin(sin(thetain)/nout)
    return thetaout

a0 = 1
thetain = 1E-16
stuff = []
thetaout = array(stuff, float)
things = []
contrast_var = array(things, float)
i=0

while (i<=360):
    thetain = (convert_degrees(thetain))
    stuff.append(find_thetaout(1.52, thetain))#1.52 is refractive index of glass
    R = theta_dependence(1, 1.52, thetain, thetaout)
    things.append(contrast(R, a0))
    i += 0.1
    thetain += 0.1

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(thetaout, contrast_var)
plt.title("Contrast vs. Theta-Out")
plt.xlabel("Theta-Out (RAD)")
plt.ylabel("Contrast (ARB)")
plt.show()
```

The issue seems to arise on line 12 with the following error:

```
  File "C:/Users/Nick/.spyder2-py3/interferometry computational.py", line 12, in theta_dependence
    R = ((nin*cos(thetain)-nout*cos(thetaout2))/(nin*cos(thetain)+nout*cos(thetaout2)))**2

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I am not sure as to what the issue is because the issue is inside a definition not where the definition is being used. Any assistance or insight with this problem would be very helpful as I have spent several hours thinking about it and trying different things to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `thetaout` in `theta_dependence(1, 1.52, thetain, thetaout)` to compute `R` but `thetaout` is an empty list as defined here: `thetaout = array(stuff, float)`. That is the reason for the eror message. Although you computed `thetaout` in `find_thetaout` function but it is a local variable there and does not modify the global `thetaout`. So, here is my suggestion:

Insert `global thetaout` statement in `find_thetaout` function as:

```
def find_thetaout(nout, thetain):
    global thetaout
    thetaout = asin(sin(thetain)/nout)
    return thetaout
```

Also in statement `plt.plot(thetaout, contrast_var)` both `thetaout` and `contrast_var` are two floats and plot takes two iterables of same length, so will throw an error. I guess you are trying to plot `stuff` and `things` which are two lists of same length. My suggestion:

Replace:

```
plt.plot(thetaout, contrast_var)
```

with:

```
plt.plot(stuff, things)
```

Comment: The issue with the last part of your solution is that I need to do math with the numbers in 'stuff' and 'things' so they need to be arrays not lists which is why I converted them to the current format. I will try the other suggestion though.

Comment: Your first correction solves the error on this thread, I am now receiving an error that 'ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension' which sounds like the error you were describing, but how can I do math with the lists without converting them to arrays?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, managed to fix it. Thank you so much for the assistance.